# Laravel Query Builder - Advanced Join and Select

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm trying to tidy up my raw query and i'm interested in wordpress meta key and meta value

How to do this with Laravel Query Builder?

```
META TABLE ==
meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value
1       | 101     | quantity | 8
2       | 101     | price    | 100
3       | 102     | quantity | 7
4       | 102     | price    | 56
5       | 103     | quantity | 12
6       | 103     | price    | 256

POST TABLE ==
post_id | about
101     | Pencil    | Luxurious pencil only for you
102     | Eraser    | All your mistakes, gone!
103     | Pen       | Unrivaled penmanship, stronger than sword.
```

Query :

```
select 
    p.post_id, 
    p.name, 
    p.about, 
    m1.meta_value, 
    m2.meta_value 
from post_table p 
    inner join meta_table m1 
        on m1.post_id = p.post_id and m1.meta_key = 'quantity' 
    inner join meta_table m2 
        on m2.post_id = p.post_id and m2.meta_key = 'price' 
where CAST(m1.meta_value as int) < 10 
order by CAST(m1.meta_value as int) asc
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I build the below query with the help of [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries) and I hope that this will work for you. I'm not tested this.

```
DB::table('post_table AS p')
          ->select('p.post_id', 'p.name', 'p.about', 'meta_value', 'meta_value')
          ->join('meta_table AS m1','m1.post_id','=','p.post_id')
          ->where('m1.meta_key', 'quantity')
          ->join('meta_table AS m2','m2.post_id','=','p.post_id')
          ->where('m2.meta_key', 'price')
          ->where(DB::raw('CAST(m1.meta_value AS INT)','<',10)
          ->orderBy(DB::raw('CAST(m1.meta_value AS INT)'), 'asc') 
          ->get();
```